# How to add an if else statement in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome-5

I am trying to an if/else statement added to this code where the toggle is already clicked to be able to click it again and change to another color

HTML

```
<a class="reme" href="#"><i class="far fa-circle"></i> Remember Me</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".reme").click(function(){
$(this).css("color", "#1ABC9C");
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('far fa-cirle fas fa-circle');
});
```

Comment: without the `HTML` part we can't really provide some help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a style to your CSS and then just `toggleClass` for the button itself - as demonstrated below.

Let me know if you wanted something else.

I have also added an `if` version below, but would advise against using it.

---

## Demo

```js
// Click event
$(".reme").click(function() { 

  // Toggle class on the button
  $(this).toggleClass("green-text");

  // Unchanged
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('far fa-cirle fas fa-circle');

});
```

```css
.green-text {
  color: #1ABC9C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="reme">Toggle</button>
```

---

## Alternative

You can use an `if` statement if you'd like, and check the inline `.css` value of `color`... but this is definitely not the best way of doing this. Toggling classes will be much better for this particular use case.

```js
// Click event
$(".reme").click(function() {

 // Check if the color is set inline to the rgb version of your color - as when changed this way it enters the hex as rgb 
 if ( $(this).css("color") == "rgb(26, 188, 156)")  {
    
    // Make it black if it is
    $(this).css("color", "black");
    
  } else {
  
    // Set it as green if not
    $(this).css("color", "#1ABC9C");
    
  }
  
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('far fa-cirle fas fa-circle');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="reme">Toggle</button>
```